# How to sort a column that have dates in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, sorting, datetime

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    SEMANAS      HIDROLOGICAS        METEOROLOGICAS
 0  02042020    36.00583090379008   31.284418529316522
 1  05032020    86.91690962099126   77.01136731748973
 2  12032020    87.31778425655976   77.24180581323434
 3  19032020    59.2201166180758    54.57343110404338
 4  26032020    32.39795918367347   29.049238743116323
```

I used this code to change df.SEMANAS to datetime

```
Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS']=pd.to_datetime(Semanas_Oper['SEMANAS'], format='%d%m%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

 SEMANAS    HIDROLOGICAS    METEOROLOGICAS
 02/04/2020    36.01           31.28
 05/03/2020    86.92           77.01
 12/03/2020    87.32           77.24
 19/03/2020    59.22           54.57
 26/03/2020    32.4            29.05
```

But pd.to_datetime is not sorting the dates of the column df.SEMANAS
Can you tell me how to sort this columns. 02/04/2020 must be in the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dt.strftime()` undoes the datetime conversion and brings you back to strings. If you sort on this, you'll be left with lexiographical sorting, not what you want given your format is `'%d/%m/%Y'` (would be fine with `'%Y/%m/%d'`).

When [working with dates in pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) you should **keep the datetime64[ns] dtype**. It's the easiest way to perform all datetime operations. Only use `.strftime` when you need to move to some other library or file output that requires a very specific string format.

```
df['SEMANAS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SEMANAS'], format='%d%m%Y')
df.dtypes
#SEMANAS           datetime64[ns]
#HIDROLOGICAS              object
#METEOROLOGICAS            object

df = df.sort_values('SEMANAS')
#     SEMANAS       HIDROLOGICAS      METEOROLOGICAS
#1 2020-03-05  86.91690962099126   77.01136731748973 
#2 2020-03-12  87.31778425655976   77.24180581323434
#3 2020-03-19   59.2201166180758   54.57343110404338 
#4 2020-03-26  32.39795918367347  29.049238743116323 
#0 2020-04-02  36.00583090379008  31.284418529316522
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort it using `datetime64` `ns` format and change it back to dd/mm/yyyy if you want

```
df['SEMANAS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SEMANAS'], format='%d%m%Y')
df.sort_values(by=['SEMANAS'], inplace=True)
df['SEMANAS'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SEMANAS'], format='%d%m%Y').dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
print(df)

      SEMANAS  HIDROLOGICAS  METEOROLOGICAS
1  05/03/2020     86.916910       77.011367
2  12/03/2020     87.317784       77.241806
3  19/03/2020     59.220117       54.573431
4  26/03/2020     32.397959       29.049239
0  02/04/2020     36.005831       31.284419
```